# Jasmine doesn't execute callbacks from $resource

Tags: angularjs, testing, resources, tdd, jasmine

So I'm having this issue when writing my tests that I don't know how to solve:

This is my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')
  .controller('SettingsExtrasCtrl', function ($scope, $log, Auth, Property, $modal, dialogs, growl) {
    $scope.deleteExtra = function(index) {
      var dlg = dialogs.confirm('Please Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to delete '+$scope.selectedProperty.extras[index].name+'?');
      dlg.result.then(function() {
        Property.removeExtra({ _id : $scope.selectedProperty._id, otherId : $scope.selectedProperty.extras[index]._id }, function(res) {
          $scope.selectedProperty.extras.splice(index,1);
          growl.success("Success message", {title : 'Success'});
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
    };
});
```

$scope.selectedProperty comes from a parent controller.

And here is my test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: SettingsExtrasCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  var SettingsExtrasCtrl, scope, stateParams, Property, httpBackend;

  var dialogs = {
    confirm: function (title, message) {
      return {
        result: {
          then: function (callback) {
            return callback();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var fakeProperty = {
    _id : 'propertyId',
    extras : [
      {
        _id : 'extraId',
        name : 'Extra'
      }
    ]
  };

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _Property_, _$httpBackend_, $state, $modal, _dialogs_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.selectedProperty = fakeProperty;
    stateParams = {propertyId: fakeProperty._id};
    Property = _Property_;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    spyOn(Property, 'removeExtra');
    spyOn(_dialogs_, 'confirm').andCallFake(dialogs.confirm);
    SettingsExtrasCtrl = $controller('SettingsExtrasCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      $stateParams: stateParams,
      dialogs: _dialogs_,
      $state: $state
    });
  }));


  it('should delete an extra', inject(function(_dialogs_) {
    httpBackend.expectDELETE('/api/properties/' + stateParams.propertyId + '/extras/someextraId').respond(200, '');
    scope.deleteExtra(0);
    expect(_dialogs_.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(Property.removeExtra).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.selectedProperty.extras.length).toBe(0);
  }));

});
```

The assert expect(scope.selectedProperty.extras.length).toBe(0); fails because expects 1 to be 0 because the success callback from Property.removeExtra is never called.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For promise to be executed you have to call a digest cycle :

```
scope.deleteExtra(0);
scope.$digest();
```

**[EDIT]**

Has it's a network call, you will have to look at [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

basically it work like that :

```
//you can mock the network call
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://url').respond(200);//status code or object

// stuff that make the call
....

$httpBackend.flush();

expect(thing).toBe(stuff);
```

A bit of doc :

*The $httpBackend used in production always responds to requests asynchronously. If we preserved this behavior in unit testing, we'd have to create async unit tests, which are hard to write, to follow and to maintain. But neither can the testing mock respond synchronously; that would change the execution of the code under test. For this reason, the mock $httpBackend has a flush() method, which allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests. This preserves the async api of the backend, while allowing the test to execute synchronously.*

Comment: Sadly I still get "Expected 1 to be 0"